# "Endpoint request timed out " error coming

Tags: spring, aws-lambda

I have a spring application and when i trigger the lambda function from API Gateway , "Endpoint request timed out" error is coming.The code is given below.

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LambdaHandler.class);

        private SpringLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest, Context context) {
        try {
            handler = SpringLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(MvcConfig.class);

        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to create handler", e);
            return null;
        }

        return handler.proxy(awsProxyRequest, context);
    }
}
```

The MvcConfig class is :-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.joeyvmason.serverless.spring"})
public class MvcConfig {
}
```

and HelloController class is :-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello(@PathVariable String id) {
                return "Hello World!";
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help